# If $f(n)$ and $g(n)$ are both $\Theta (h(n))$ then is it true that $f(n)$ is $\Theta (g(n))$ and $g(n)$ is $\Theta (f(n))$?

Tags: asymptotics

My question is exactly what the title says. If two functions are $\Theta$ of another function then are they $\Theta$ of each other. I know that this is not the case with big $O$ but does it work with $\Theta$ because $\Theta$ bounds on both sides?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exactly right.

If
$f(n)
=\Theta(h(n))
$
and
$g(n)
=\Theta(h(n))
$,
then there are constants
$a, b, c, d$ such that,
for large enough $n$,
$a 
< \frac{f(n)}{h(n)}
< b
$
and
$c 
< \frac{g(n)}{h(n)}
< d
$.

Therefore
$\frac{a}{d}
< \frac{f(n)}{g(n)}
< \frac{b}{c}
$
so
$f(n)= \Theta(g(n))
$
and
$g(n) =\Theta(f(n))
$.